# Feed not showing up correctly on Android App?

Tags: bug, android-app

[image: Bug screenshot]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Huawei
- Device Model: Nexus 6P

  - OS Version: 7.0 (3051502)

Comment: @rene Yes, I believe this is a duplicate